# Find a chain of fields $F \subseteq E \subseteq K$, where $E \cong F[X]/(X^2 + X + 1)$ and $K \cong E[X]/(X^3 - a)$ for some $a \in E$.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $F \subseteq E \subseteq K$ a chain of fields, such that the characteristic of $F$ is neither $2$ nor $3$, and we suppose that we have found $z \in K$, with $K = E(z)$, and $a \in E$ such that $\min(z , E)(X) = X^3 - a$.

We suppose also that $E = F(x)$, with $[E : F] = 2$, such that $x$ is a root of the polynomial $X^2 + X + 1$ (so $x$ is a primitive cube root of unity). $K / E$ and $E / F$ have to be Galois extensions. Can we take $a$ such that $a \in F$? I only look for an example.

I thought in $F = \mathbb{Q}$, $E = F(e^{2 \pi i/3})$ and $K = E(\sqrt[3]{2})$ and $a = 2$, I am not sure if $K / E$ is normal though.

Comment: If $z$ is a root of $X^3-a$, then so are $xz$ and $x^2z$, so $K/E$ is necessarily normal.

Answer (score 1):

In general you cannot take $a\in F$; your example is close to a counterexample:

Take $F = \mathbb{Q}$ and $E = F\left(e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}\right)$, and
$$K=E\left(e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{9}}\right).$$
Then we may take $z=e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{9}}$, but $\min(z,E)=X^3-e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}$.

In fact, for any choice of non-cube $a\in\mathbb{Q}$, adjoining a root $z$ of $X^3-a$ to $E=\mathbb{Q}(e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}})$ yields a splitting field of $X^3-a$, which has Galois group $S_3$, whereas $K=\mathbb{Q}(e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{9}})$ has Galois group $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What do you mean? Cannot I take $a \in F$?

Comment: But this $a$ does not belong to $F$. Cannot I take $a \in F$?

Comment: No; the latter argument shows that no element from $F$ can give rise to such an extension $K$.

Comment: Why cannot I take $a \in F$?

Comment: Because for any $a\in F$ we have $\operatorname{Gal}(E[X]/(X^3-a)/F)\cong S_3$, whereas $\operatorname{Gal}(E[X]/(X^3-x)/F)\cong\Bbb{Z}/6\Bbb{Z}$. Here $x\in E$ is a root of $X^2+X+1$.

Comment: Which is the mistake in my example?

Comment: @joseabp91 There is no mistake as such in your example; this answer just shows that it not always true that $a \in F$ when the given conditions are satisfied. Sometimes $a \in F$ as in your example, sometimes it is not as in this answer.